# Grouping unique values from an SQL column as headings, another column as subheadings and another as sub-subheadings Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with columns and values similar to:

```
|country  |region  |city       |
|------------------------------|
|USA      |Maine   |Bar Harbor |
|Australia|Victoria|Melbourne  |
|Spain    |Valencia|Enguera    |
|Australia|Victoria|Colbo      |
|USA      |New York|NYC        |
```

I'd like to display this in alphabetical order like this:

```
Australia
 Victoria
  Colbo
  Melbourne

Spain
 Valencia
  Enguera

USA
 Maine
  Bar Harbor
 New York
  NYC
```

I have attempted to use nested for loops which I found suggested in this question: [How do I get unique values from a column and group them with values from another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697734/how-do-i-get-unique-values-from-a-column-and-group-them-with-values-from-another)
But I've had difficulty adding the third value column.

Comment: I am getting the right values from the table and in the right order but I haven't managed to remove the duplicate values yet. I've been tangling with arrays but I'm not sure I fully understand the way SQL results from a multiple column call are structured. Could someone please point me in the direction of a tutorial where I can learn how to "After each iteration save the last record . . . If it doesn't equal the previous." I've been using W3Schools and Codecademy but I've been reviewing those resources for the last week with no elucidation whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

- Select from the given table order by country, region, city.
- Loop through the result set and print the fields. (with the exceptions I describe below.) (X)
- After each iteration save the last record

  - (X) print only the country if it doesn't equal with the previous
  - (X) and print only the region if the country/region doesn't equal with the previous.

(when you skip a printing, you can print a few spaces, to create a tabulated like view like in your example.)

Answer (score 0):

hopefully work

```
    select country,region,city from table group by country,region 
order by country asc,region desc ,city desc
```